# Declare and use variable in same statement

Tags: c

In C is it valid to use a variable in the same statement in which it is declared?

In both gcc 4.9 and clang 3.5 the following program compiles and runs without error:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
  int x = x;
  printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

In gcc it outputs `0` and in clang `32767` (which is largest positive 2-byte integer value).

Why does this not cause a compilation error? Is this valid in any particular C specification? Is its behavior explicitly undefined?

Comment: In MSVC it outputs "warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used". Please enable compiler warnings before asking silly questions.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The fact that a compiler issues a warning doesn't tell you whether it's valid.

Comment: MSVC outputs at runtime `-1373317485` Well, once, various values.

Comment: @KeithThompson it is a pretty strong indicator. As you well know, C does not protect you against yourself.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's a pretty strong indicator that it's not something you should do, but that wasn't the question. [reposting comment to fix typo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int x = x;
```

This is "valid" in the sense that it doesn't violate a constraint or syntax rule, so no compile-time diagnostic is required.  The name `x` is visible within the initializer, and refers to the object being declared. The scope is defined in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.1 paragraph 7:

> Any other identifier *[other than a struct, union, or enum tag, or
>   an enum constant]* has scope that begins just after the completion of
>   its declarator.

The *declarator* in this case is `int x`.

This allows for things like:

```
int x = 10, y = x + 1;
```

But the declaration has undefined behavior, because the initializer refers to an object that hasn't been initialized.

The explicit statement that the behavior is undefined is in N1570 6.3.2.1 paragraph 2, which describes the "conversion" of an lvalue (an expression that designates an object) to the value stored in that object.

> Except when *[list of cases that don't apply here]*, an
>   lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored
>   in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called
>   *lvalue conversion*.
>   *[...]*
>   If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that
>   could have been declared with the **`register`** storage class (never
>   had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared
>   with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior
>   to use), the behavior is undefined.

The object in question is `x`, referenced in the initializer. At that point, no value has been assigned to `x`, so the expression has undefined behavior.

In practice, you'll probably get a compile-time warning if you enable a high enough warning level. The actual behavior *might* be the same as if you had omitted the initializer:

```
int x;
```

but don't count on it.

Comment: Would it make a difference if code had been `unsigned char x = x;`?  [C11 6.2.6.2 1]

Comment: That's all correct, but it sort of sidesteps the issue. You could use self-referential initialization to construct circular lists, for example: `struct node {int value; struct node *next, *prev;} x = (struct node){argc, &x, &x};`.  As far as I know that is legal and produces the expected result.

Comment: @chux: I don't think so. 6.3.2.1p2 still applies.

Comment: @rici: What issue is being sidestepped? Your example doesn't apply to the OP's declaration `int x = x;`. And it's not evaluating the value of the object, it's just taking its address, which is well defined whether it's been initialized or not.

Comment: @keith: precisely, but it is only legal because the variable is already in scope at that point, which would not be the case in many other languages. That is, to my mind, the issue raised by the question in the title.

Comment: @rici: I've added a citation showing where the scope begins.

Answer (score 2):

According to the language specification

> 6.7.8.10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Further, it says

> 6.7.8.11 The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion).

Hence, the value of the initializer expression (`x` to the right of `=`) is *indeterminate*, so we are dealing with undefined behavior, because initializer reads from variable `x` that has indeterminate value.

Various compilers provide warning settings to catch such conditions.

Comment: You missed the part that makes it undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - wouldn't `its value is indeterminate.` be equal to UB?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Not immediately. Having an indeterminate value around is not a UB, as long as you do not read it prior to an assignment. That's why I edited the answer to clarify David's point.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = x;
```

is cause for undefined behavior. Don't count on any predictable behavior.

Comment: Any reference to the standard that would show this? I agree with you that intuitively, it's undefined behavior. It would be nice to have an authoritative source, though.

Comment: It's the lvalue to rvalue conversion that's UB since the value is indeterminate.

Comment: @Sjlver, I couldn't find anything more than what dasblinkenlight quoted.

Comment: There's an explicit statement that an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion whose value is indeterminate is UB.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I cited it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clang does warn about this:

```
$ clang -c -Wall ub_or_not_ub.c
ub_or_not_ub.c:4:11: warning: variable 'x' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
  int x = x;
      ~   ^
```

So I guess it's undefined behavior.